# Herencia (Pregunta certificación JAVA)

Tags: java, herencia

tengo una duda con respecto a una pregunta de herencia, esto es para el examen de certificación de programming, me pueden apoyar de favor con alguna explicación. 
No logro comprender porque imprime DerivedB Derived B (Sale esto dado que ya lo compile)
Gracias!

```
class Base{
    public void test(){
       System.out.println("Base ");
    }
}

class DerivedA extends Base{
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("DerivadA ");
    }
}

class DerivedB extends DerivedA{
    public void test(){
        System.out.println("DerivadB ");
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
        Base b1 = new DerivedB();
        Base b2 = new DerivedA();
        Base b3 = new DerivedB(); 
        b1 = (Base) b3;
        Base b4 = (DerivedA) b3;
        b1.test();
        b2.test();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

class DerivedB extends DerivedB

Estas dandole extend a la misma clase, deberia darte error por eso por cierto, cambia

class DerivedB extends DerivedA y todo deberia funcionar

Comment: Tienes razón, era extends DerivedA. Al hacer el cambio porque imprime DerivedB en dos ocasiones